# OBD/OBD2 port on a 1993 mitsubishi triton MJ

Tags: obd-ii, obd-i

Does anyone know if there is an ODB2 diagnostics port on a 1993 Mitsubishi Triton MJ 4x4 Ute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely, but I can't say for certain.  AFAIK, Mitsubishi first started putting OBD-II diagnostics ports into the 1995 model year cars (in preparation for the 1996 OBD-II requirement).

Most likely is OBD-I, which would require a proprietary plug (or jumpering of a couple pins) to read/force a code display.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I couldn't find one in the normal place so I assumed it wouldn't have.